# Chrome error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, redirect

I have a website Backend (Admin Panel), before some days it was working good, but now a days it shows me an error when i logout from the panel. It shows me something like this-

```
The web page isn’t working

web redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Update:

After i click on `logout` button, i have a page where i unset the sessions and then `header("location: login.php");`.

What should i do to take this off for my admin panel.

Comment: have you implemented redirect after logout? please post that code

Comment: Yes, updates are added to the question.

Comment: ok..have you any redirect in login.php also

Comment: Yes, But they are under a specific conditions... Like: I check if session is set then goto `home.php` and another is if i want to login then check inside the `$_POST['submit']` and redirect to the `home.php`.

Comment: thats the problem? can you post that code also , i was facing this error and solved by removing a condition

Comment: I think this is not efficient, cause i have a large amount of code, I describe what i has in my codes.

Comment: but thats the problem bro ,check your condition then or paste code which contain condition

Comment: It is a deadlock/loop. You are redirecting again and again from one location to another just because something is not cleared or not set properly. You must check all your conditions again peacefully...

Comment: I got the solution, I need to unset all the session that i start in this project. The condition is not doing any problem.